# field_attach_form with user picture and user mail?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to build a custom "edit profile" page and use a lot the field_attach_form function in order to build it :

```
field_attach_form('user', $user_entity, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => 'field_user_firstname'));
field_attach_form('user', $user_entity, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => 'field_user_lastname'));
field_attach_form('user', $user_entity, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => 'field_user_organisation'));
```

I'm trying to insert input for user mail and user picture, but as they are properties and not fields, the following snippet is not working.

```
field_attach_form('user', $user_entity, $form, $form_state, NULL, array('field_name' => 'mail'));
```

Is it possible to insert user's properties form with this function ? or is there another way ?

Comment: Have you ever thought about a solution with display suite?

Comment: field_attach_form only attaches... Fields. You will have to use user_account_form directly and tinker around. I had to do this, and ended up creating a custom form wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kkalaskar i managed to do what I was looking for :

```
function _my_module_edit_profile() {
  global $user;
  $user_entity = user_load($user->uid);
  $var['form'] = drupal_get_form('_my_module_edit_profile_form',$user_entity);
  return render($var['form']);
}

function _my_module_edit_profile_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $account = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];
  if (!isset($form_state['user'])) {
    $form_state['user'] = $account;
  }
  else {
    $account = $form_state['user'];
  }
  $form['#user'] = $account;
  $form['#user_category'] = 'account';
  user_account_form($form, $form_state);
  $langcode = entity_language('user', $account);
  field_attach_form('user', $account, $form, $form_state, $langcode);

  $form['account']['#access'] = false;
  $form['field_user_initialized']['#access'] = false;

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Done !'),
    '#weight' => 100
  );
  $form['#validate'][] = 'user_profile_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'user_profile_form_submit';
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a similar task; my task was to put the address field into the popup and I used the following code to accomplish it. I looked at modules/user/user.page.inc for it.

```
    function MYMODULE_init() {
         //To avoid user_profile_form_validate function not found
         module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
         } //end init function

        //Custom form for fields
        function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {

        $form = array();
        global $user;
        $account = user_load($user->uid);

        if (!isset($form_state['user'])) {
            $form_state['user'] = $account;
          }
          else {
            $account = $form_state['user'];
          }

        $form['#user'] = $account;
        user_account_form($form, $form_state);
        // Attach field widgets.
            $langcode = entity_language('user', $account);
            field_attach_form('user', $account, $form, $form_state, $langcode);
        //All fields get attached so removing unnecessary fields.  
            unset($form['account']['pass']);
            unset($form['account']['roles']);
 $key = array_search('user_validate_current_pass', form['#validate']);
    if ($key !== FALSE) {
      unset($form['#validate'][$key]);
    }
    // hide the current password fields
    $form['account']['current_pass_required_value']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['account']['current_pass']['#access'] = FALSE;

            $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
            $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Save'),
           );

          $form['actions']['cancel'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Cancel'),
            '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_form_cancel'),
            '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
          );
          $form['#validate'][] = 'user_profile_form_validate';
          // Add the final user profile form submit handler.
          $form['#submit'][] = 'user_profile_form_submit';

          return $form;
        }

        // Add function for CANCEL button.
        function MYMODULE_form_cancel(&$form_state) {
        $url = $_GET['destination'] ? $_GET['destination'] : 'choose/your/path';
          drupal_goto($url);
        }
```